# Adding links in Excel with macro

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, cname

i have script which is doing wright thing for me, but I can use it just in single cell.

```
    Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim CName As String

CName = ActiveCell
'
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        "SWFdataEN\DOKUMENTE\C00\04%20TB031\" & CName, TextToDisplay _
        :=CName
End Sub
```

It is adding link to filename which is written in this cell (CName) and sets TextToDisplay in same name (CName).

How can I apply this macro in next cell in column (like i hit enter and run macro again) automatically? I tried with For-Next loop, but no good results. Script always puts link of same first filename, but TextToDisply is correct.
Help please

Comment: You use `ActiveCell` and `Selection` as if they were two different things. If only one cell is selected, they are the same cell. Can you clear up: anchor for the hyperlink and target filename - which one cshould be the activecell and from where do you get the other one?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out this:

In a public module, you insert your macro:

```
Sub sofMacro1()
'
  Dim CName As String

  CName = ActiveCell
'
  If (CName <> "") Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
      "SWFdataEN\DOKUMENTE\C00\04%20TB031\" & CName, TextToDisplay _
      :=CName
  End If
'
End Sub
```

Then in the current Worksheet, you add an event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  sofMacro1
End Sub
```

It adds a Hyperlink to any cell that contains text (not empty), when you move your cursor anywhere in the ActiveSheet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I get right text to display like you, but all links are still linked to 1st file! So..

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong with VBA, I have Modules\Module 1 with first part of code, and Class Modules\Class 1 with second part. Does anything else need?

Comment: Part II must not be in a class module, but in the private module of the worksheet on which you add hyperlinks.

Comment: It is not what I looking for but it's speed up my work! Thanks. I was looking for solution when I select range of cell then run macro, I macro puts links on each cell.